# Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `href`. If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: href="true" or href={value.toString()}

Tags: reactjs

I have ahref like this. Where on clicking a link, users are redirected to Youtube.

```
    const handleExternal =()=>{
      window.open("https://youtu.be/rygassaje9LuM", '_blank'); 
  
  }



<li className='leftmenu__menuitem'>
<div>
<span> <a href onClick={handleExternal}>Click here</a> to see how to see Embed Youtube</span>
</div>
</li>
```

But, I'm getting this error

```
Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `href`. If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: href="true" or href={value.toString()}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Passing a prop with no value is treated as a boolean `true`. This doesn't makes sense for a `href` - therefore you get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `href` is supposed to have a value. Passing `<a href>text</a>` will pass the value of href as `true`. You have to pass a string to `href`.

`<a href>text</a>` is equivalant to `<a href={true}>text</a>`

For example `<a href="https://google.com">text</a>`

Or if you want to pass a variable:

```
const url="https://google.com";
...
...
return (
    <a href={url}>text</a>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`href` attribute takes a **string** value, but you're actually passing a **boolean**. To understand this behavior check this;

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-default-to-true